# How to tell if a query has come to an end

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I am building a report using php and mysql, i have multiple queries going on in one go on one page and as you can imagine this is putting a lot of stress on the server, now what i wish to do is get the first query to start and before launching the second query, it checks if the first query has finished and it goes on like this until it reaches the last query. And just to be clear, one query at a time does not put that much stress on the server but several in one go does. If anybody has any idea or has an alternative please let me know.

Comment: You should give an example of the code you're using, usually queries with php are not parallelized

Comment: How have you managed to create threads in a PHP script? Can you share your code or at least explain how you accomplish it?

Comment: It is a straight forward count query (select count(X) from tabley inner join tablez on tabley.id=tablez.id where criterias match), which goes through a loop, each time it changes a few variable within the query itself.

Comment: Do you use fancy stuff like this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.poll.php and this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php ?

Comment: @RoddyDairion - And today it's Tuesday. Now, could you please provide the requested info? Thank you!

Comment: I see what you mean @ÁlvaroG.Vicario , so php will always run in sequence, and will never run multiple query at the same time. So i am guessing that there's no fix for this, I just have to let be.

Comment: While PHP is single threaded, there are ways to emulate multi-tasking—I assumed you were using one of those, in which case the answer to "how to control running queries" depends entirely on how you launch them (thus the absolute need to see code). Now you say you don't do any of those fancy things but add "no fix for this". Fix for what? If you don't have concurrent queries, what needs to be fixed?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario the speed at which the number gets generated but that i will apply with indexes, i know that the mysql server allows multi-thread, but from the reply i received from you guys, i just realised that when it comes to php it will be sequential. I knew the answer to this, i guess this is the time to stop scripting and go  to bed. Thank you all for your replies, i would have tried all night.

Comment: Alright, have a nice sleep :) Whatever... If you have two slow running queries *on the same tables*, executing them at the same time is possibly the worst idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, PHP will not execute next MySQL query or any other code at all before previous query is finished.

Comment: Got it. Any idea to speed up the process, i have already indexed, what had to be indexed.